# Ошибка в авторизации пользователя

Tags: php

Есть код файла обработчика авторизации:

```
<?php
$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = filter_var(trim($_POST['pass']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$pass = md5($pass."abcdefg1234567890");
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'cc36637_soc', 'admin', 'cc36637_soc');
$res = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$pass'");
$user = $res->fetch_assoc();
if(count($user) == 0){   
  header('Location: index.php'); 
  exit();
}
//setcookie('user', $user['name'], time()+15, "/");
$mysql->close();
header('Location: page.php');
?>
```

Его задача проверить, есть ли в базе пользователь с введенными паролем и логином, и если да, 
то перенаправить на следующую страницу. А если нет, то вывести на странице с формой 
"такого пользователя не существует".

Дело в том, что файл обработчик - auth.php, а файл с формой это index.php.

Никак не могу дописать условия обработчика и вывести ошибку на странице индекса.

Comment: что возвращает $user ?

Comment: всех пользователей из таблицы, которые подошли (т.е. у которых логин и пароль совпал с введенными)

Comment: В данном случае `на странице с формой "такого пользователя не существует".`, не иначе как ajax вас только спасет.
Вы на `index.php`, заполняете форму, отправляете на `auth.php`, там идет проверка и решение, есть он или нет, далее вы просто делаете редирект на целевую страинцу, `index.php` понятия не имеет о форме, которую вы отпарвили ДО, либо же сессии, куки, localstorage юзайте, и проверку на `index.php`, есть запись токена или чего-то там еще в вышеупомянутых харилищах или нет, если нет, то выводите вы свое сообщение, если есть, welcome, как говорится.

Comment: Cпасибо, понял)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>Поля формы и тп.</form>

$.(document).on('click', '.button-submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: .../auth.php,
        method: POST,
        data: {username: $.('селектор на тергетинговые данные username'), тп.}
        success: {function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $.('селектор на контейнер с сообщением о успешной проверке или не успешной').html('response.message') или .append('response.message');
             }
        }}
    });
});
```

---

Код для примера.